# Firebase sorting data in desc using negative timestamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data in descending order at server side, which I am doing using negative timestamps. In my client side code, I am ordering data using timestamp for first few items, using this query:

```
Query queryRef = databaseReference.child("wallpapers").orderByChild("timeStamp").limitToFirst(6)
```

I am maintaining a variable (`oldestPostId`) which keeps hold of last key added to list.

Then I am using `onScrollListener` to retrieve more data using this query:-

```
Query queryRef = databaseReference.child("wallpapers").orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(oldestPostId).limitToFirst(6);
```

First 6 items are correctly retrieved but my `onScrollListener` query i.e. second query not working.
According to me, If there are 4 items lets say 1,2,3,4 which if ordered are 1,4,3,2. Let's suppose if I am retrieving 3 items at once, then first I will get 1,4,3 and in another query, I should get 3,2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, oldestPostId is the last key you added to list. I assume it will be the random generated key Firebase assigned to your wallpaper object when you push it to the database.

It means that, the oldestPostId is not the timeStamp.

Your second query is trying to extract the first 6 item with timeStamp>=oldestPostId, which is not comparing apple to apple. Ofcourse it is not working. You should use oldestPostTimestamp inside your query instead of olderstPostId.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying to order by the `timeStamp` child and you are passing to the `startAt()` method an `id` and not a `timeStamp` value. In order to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query queryRef = databaseReference.child("wallpapers").orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(oldestPostId).limitToFirst(6);
```

with

```
Query queryRef = databaseReference.child("wallpapers")
    .orderByChild("timeStamp")
    .startAt(1523346011) //We pass a timeStamp
    .limitToFirst(6);
```

As you can see, I have passed to `startAt()` a `timeStamp` which is of type long.